# Why do I get a FrameTooBig error when using Tokio's frame_delimited?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to get my feet wet using Tokio. When I send a message from a Telnet connection, I get `Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: FrameTooBig }`. I don't understand the issue, nor how to overcome it.

```
extern crate tokio;
extern crate tokio_io;

use tokio::io;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio_io::codec::length_delimited;

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:12345".parse().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).unwrap();

    let server = listener
        .incoming()
        .for_each(|socket| {
            let transport = length_delimited::Builder::new().new_read(socket);
            let msg_proccessing = transport
                .for_each(|msg| {
                    // Note: This part is never actually executed
                    println!("{:?}", msg);
                    Ok(())
                })
                .map_err(|e| println!("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {:?}", e));
            tokio::spawn(msg_proccessing);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|_| {});
    tokio::run(server);
}
```

Client side:

```
▶ telnet localhost 12345                                     
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
\x00\x00\x00\x0bhello world
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was lying on the client side, and it was related with how Telnet works. It's not straightforward to send hex data using Telnet, so I tried this and worked well:

```
echo '\x00\x00\x00\x0bhello world' | nc localhost 12345  #WORKS!
```

However, neither of these work:

1. ```
   echo '\x00\x00\x00\x0bhello world' | telnet localhost
   ```
2. ```
   ▶ telnet localhost 12345                                     
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   \x00\x00\x00\x0bhello world
   Connection closed by foreign host.
   ```

It seems like the `FrameTooBig` error was due to the fact that the message telnet was sending was bigger than what the server expected. I wasn't be able to encode the frame properly using hex, and then the length was not matching the length header received, and thus the error.